# trying to search and replace "[" opening square bracket

Tags: python

I'm new to python, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question:

I have an XML file which I'm carrying out a number of search and replaces. One of the things I need to replace is a space followed by [ with just [ (no space before). I've tried the following but keep getting an error:

```
line = re.sub(' [','[',line)
```

and I assume its because the square brackets is used for wildcards, but I don't know what the syntax should be in order to get this to work

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No need for regex here at all. This will do fine:

```
line = line.replace(' [', '[')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `[` with a backslash:

```
line = re.sub(r' \[','[',line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> line=' [stuff]'
>>> re.sub(' \[','[',line)
'[stuff]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `sub` from the regular expression package, you need to escape the bracket since it is used to express character ranges in regular expressions (e.g. [a-z]):

```
line = re.sub(' \[','[',line)
```